# Override the dataset function

Tags: javascript

Can someone advice me on how I can override the dataset prototype function?

This is my attempt so far:

```
if (document.createElement('div').dataset === undefined) {
  console.log('IE FIX');
  HTMLElement.prototype.dataset = function() {
    console.log('Fired?');
    this.menu = 'test';
  }
}
```

I call it like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-menu]')[0].dataset.menu
```

Currently all i'm getting in the console is:

> IE FIX

I should be getting `Fired?` at least?

**Edit 2**

See below code, this still doesn't display the console.log

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  if (document.createElement('div').dataset !== undefined) {
    Object.defineProperty(
      HTMLElement.prototype,
      'dataset',
      {
        value: function () { console.log('dsada'); }
      }
    )
  }

  document.querySelectorAll('[data-menu]')[0].dataset;

});
```

Sort of works in the console:

> Command: document.createElement('div').dataset

```
function () { console.log('dsada'); }
```

It should execute the function though.

**Edit 3**

Modified the code, using `value` should simply be a value, and not a function. I changed it to `get` which expects a function and executes it.

- **accessor descriptor** = get + set (see the example above)

  - **get** must be a function; its return value is used in reading the property; if not specified, the default is undefined, which behaves like a function that returns undefined
  - **set** must be a function; its parameter is filled with RHS in assigning a value to property; if not specified, the default is undefined, which behaves like an empty function
- **data descriptor** = value + writable (see the example below)

  - **value** default undefined; if writable, configurable and enumerable (see below) are true, the property behaves like an ordinary data field
  - **writable** - default false; if not true, the property is read only; attempt to write is ignored without error*!

Below code displays the element correctly

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  if (document.createElement('div').dataset !== undefined) {
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'dataset', {
      get: function () {
        console.log(this);

      }
    })
  }

  document.querySelectorAll('[data-menu]')[0].dataset;

});
```

My question now, is there a way to handle something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-menu]')[0].dataset.menu
```

like so:

```
if (document.createElement('div').dataset !== undefined) {
  Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'dataset', {
    get: function () {
      console.log(this);
      this.getAttribute('data-' + this.arg);
    }
  })
}
```

Where this.arg would be

> document.querySelectorAll('[data-menu]')[0].dataset **.menu**

Comment: Don't you want to put it on the `HTMLElement` prototype?

Comment: Hmm, I did think it should be that, updated my code

Comment: `dataset` is a property, not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(
    HTMLElement.prototype,
    'dataset',
    {
        value: function () { /* whatever */ }
    }
)
```

Comment: See Edit 2 and advice please?

Comment: Check the source code out: https://github.com/epiloque/element-dataset/

Comment: @notgiorgi I tried to have a look at this, however I couldn't figure out where it handles for example the **menu** part in the following: `HTMLElement.dataset.menu`